Assigning an Observable based on the value of a signal
In my app, I declare a movies list based on the menu item selected (top movies, upcoming movies...).
I was doing that with a BehaviorSubject in a service with the following code:
in my component:
readonly movies$: Observable<Movie[]> = this.storeService.menuItemSelected$.pipe(
  switchMap(menuItem => {
    return menuItem === 'watchlist' ? this.movieService.getWatchlistMovies() 
      : this.movieService.getMoviesByCategory(menuItem);
  })
);

in my service:
private readonly menuItemSelectedSource = new BehaviorSubject<Category>('now_playing');
readonly menuItemSelected$ = this.menuItemSelectedSource.asObservable();

updateMenuSelection(menuItem: Category): void {
  this.menuItemSelectedSource.next(menuItem);
}

Now I'm trying to do the same but using a signal for menuItemSelected instead of a BehaviorSubject.
I made the following changes:
menuItemSelected = signal<Category>('now_playing');

updateMenuSelection(menuItem: Category): void {
  this.menuItemSelected.set(menuItem);
}

My question is, how do I declare my movies$ Observable based on that menuItemSelected signal ?
readonly movies$: Observable<Movie[]> = ... ?

Convert the signal to an observable using toObservable from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop', then substitute it with the behaviour subject
import { toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';
import { signal } from '@angular/core';
...

...
menuItemSelected = signal<Category>('now_playing');

updateMenuSelection(menuItem: Category): void {
    this.menuItemSelected.set(menuItem);
}

readonly movies$: Observable<Movie[]> = toObservable(this.storeService.menuItemSelected).pipe(
      switchMap(menuItem => {
          return menuItem === 'watchlist' ? this.movieService.getWatchlistMovies() 
            : this.movieService.getMoviesByCategory(menuItem);
      })
);
...

